# Is there any way to apply De Morgan's law to dynamic query in Spring Data Solr?

Tags: spring, solr, criteria, spring-data-solr

I've got the following problem:

Solr seems to not like and return anything when a part of my dynamically generated criteria contains only negations, like this:

```
 AND (-title_facet:*title* AND -title_facet:*List*)
```

(Which is a Crotch, created from two separate Criteria)

As this really makes a problem, is there any way to apply De Morgan's law to said criteria so it would be:

```
AND -(title_facet:*title* OR title_facet:*List*)
```

?

I'm using Spring-data-solr 1.5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `AND (-title_facet:*title* AND -title_facet:*List*)` doesn't work, is because it doesn't have anything to subtract the matching documents from.

Solr works around this when you use it as a single query by appending the set of all documents in front of your query, but when you're doing the same thing further into a query, that won't be present.

```
AND (*:* AND -title_facet:*title* AND -title_facet:*List*)
```

.. should work, since you then have a proper set of documents (all the documents) which you can subtract those matching the other two sets from.

Comment: Would your reason also apply when the criteria I posted was a part of a bigger crotch? Full criteria I'm passing to Solr are:

`(createdBy_facet:*name1* OR createdBy_facet:*name2*) AND (-title_facet:*title* AND -title_facet:*List*)`

Comment: Yes, my guess is that it would be required for the latter AND-part. The first part is just positive matches (meaning that they select documents), so there is no need for it there - but the later term only removes documents, so you have to start with something to subtract the documents from.

Comment: From what I tested it seems to be working fine, so thanks for the help!